# Specifying the tags on the environment during environment creation

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I can't seem to figure out how to add tags to an environment during creation.

So, I call the .\config.cmd script like so:

```
.\config.cmd  --unattended --environment --environmentname $environmentName --agent $env:COMPUTERNAME --runasservice --work '_work' --url $organization --projectname $project --auth PAT --token $pat --addDeploymentGroupTags --deploymentGroupTags $tags
```

This seems to work, though when I go to the resource in the environment that just got created, the tags are not there.

The tag parameter is a comma delaminated value. This is exactly how it looks like:

```
panel:1,iottech:eflow,test
```

Reading the documentation, it seems like the tags are only added when it is a deployment group. The option does not seem to be available for environments?

As a side note, I can't add the tags through the rest api either, and the official azure devops cli does not yet support managing environments.

Does this really mean that the only way to add tags to a environment is to go to the environments window in the DevOps portal and add them myself manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the commend:

```
--addvirtualmachineresourcetags --virtualmachineresourcetags "<tag>"
```

to add the tag when we create the vms in the evvironment.